# Uri mismatch in google sign-in oAuth

Tags: react-native, youtube-data-api, google-signin, google-authentication

I am working on a react-native application where I need to integrate the google sign in, and after that, I need to get the list of associated youtube channels with selected email id. Somewhere I read that this youtube channel selection flow is not available on the native android library. so I have opted Web Flow. But the issue is that I want to use custom URI eg : package://scheme for this so that I can get the callback inside my app. my current URI looks like as shown below. But every time it gives an error that redirect_uri_mismatch, Even after using this link "https://links.dev.myserver.in" invalid redirect URLs in the google API console.

Please guide me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data android:host="links.dev.myserver.in" android:scheme="http"/>
           <data android:host="links.dev.myserver.in" android:scheme="https"/>